# Is "of" as idiomatic as "about" in this context?

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

> This is a documentary about a cult that led to thousands of deaths.
>
> This a documentary of a cult that led to thousands of deaths.

Are both grammatical and idiomatic? I am used to seeing "about" a lot more, and "of" seems to be OK, but a bit vague, because "of" can mean many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This a documentary *about* a cult that led to thousands of deaths.

The word "about" is preferable. It makes clear that the cult is the subject, not the producer of the documentary.